# Converting tuple to list using shorthand notation anonymous function

Tags: elixir

Working through Dave's (PragProg) Elixir book. Challenge is to convert pair of tuples to list.

This works

```
pair = fn {a,b} -> [a,b] end
pair.({1,2}) #=> [1,2]
```

Now I tried using shorthand notation (I felt something is missing but don't know what it is...for e.g. how do I say I am expecting/sending a tuple)

How can I achieve the same results using shorthand notation?

```
pair = &([&1,&2]) 
pair.({1,2}) #=> BadArityError
```

Tried this

```
pair = &{[&1,&2]} # but didn't work. I am missing something important
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does not work because the `{a, b}` is one argument, so it gets passed as `&1`, there is no `&2`.

One way to do it that I can think of is to use `Tuple.to_list/1` function so it would be like this:

```
pair = &Tuple.to_list/1
pair.({1,2}) #=> [1,2]
```

but if this is not what you want, then you could use something like this:

```
pair = &([elem(&1, 0), elem(&1, 1)])
pair.({1,2}) #=> [1,2]
```

but this is a simple example that works only with 2 elements tuples but it will let you understand what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I deliberately wanted to avoid existing module functions such as `to_list`